# What is the meaning of this theorem regarding periodic functions?

Tags: functions

I recently got acquainted with a theorem:

If $f(x)$ is a periodic function with period $P$, then $f(ax+b)$ is periodic with period $\dfrac{P}{a}$ , $a>0$.

I am having a difficulty in understanding this theorem. Does this theorem mean that $f(ax+b)=f(ax+b+ \dfrac{P}{a})$?

If the above meaning is true, then how can a function, initially having a single period, acquire another period by just changing the arguments?

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(ax+b)$.  Then $g(x+\frac Pa)=f(a(x+\frac Pa)+b)=f(ax+b+P)=f(ax+b)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct interpretation is: the new function $g(x):=f(ax+b)$ has period $\frac{P}{a}$. Thus, $g(x+\frac{P}{a})=g(x)$. Using periodicity $P$ of $f$ we have:
\begin{equation}
g(x+\frac{P}{a})=f(a(x+\frac{P}{a})+b)=f(ax+b+P)=f(ax+b)=g(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: So, $f(x)$ and $f(ax+b)$ are different functions?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, $f(x)$ is not necessarily equal to $f(ax+b)$.

Comment: @User to be fair this doesn't prove that the period is $\frac Pa$. I mean note that $\sin(x + 4k\pi) = \sin(x)$, but the period of the function is $T = 2k\pi$

Comment: @Stefan4024 My answer is not the proof of the theorem, but its interpretation. I understand that the question was about the interpretation of the result, not about a rigorous proof.

Comment: @User Anyway, I just wanted you and the OP to be aware of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it easier let's define $g(x) = f(ax + b)$. We want to prove that the period of $g$ is $\frac Pa$. Now we have:

$$g(x + \frac Pa) = f(a\left(x + \frac Pa\right) + b) = f(ax + P + b) = f(ax + b) = g(x)$$

Hence the period is a divisor of $\frac Pa$. Once can easily show that it's the period in fact. Assume that $T$ is the period of $g$, then:

$$g(x + T) = g(x) \implies f(ax + aT + b) = f(ax + b) \implies aT = kP \implies T = \frac {kP}a$$

But we know that $T \le \frac Pa$, hence $k= \frac Pa$